# How to add dx3d cpp App to game hub in WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8

1st create a new sample direct3d porject with c++, PhoneDirect3DApp.
2nd change "WMAppManifest.xml" file's "Genre" from "Apps.normal" to "Apps.games".
3rd call VS Debug and exit apps by back.

and then,
it does not appear in GameHub neither in app list. so I even can't launch the app again.

what's wrong i made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem you've done nothing wrong - this appears to be is a either by-design or a bug in the platform for native (i.e. not .NET/XAML) non-XBOX live titles such as you are describing.

See [this thread on the Microsoft social forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/wpdevelop/thread/03a69208-14e5-44fc-aed0-7860b5cb6321)  about this topic.

Beware that in addition that this has been known to cause Store certification failures.

Store discussions however are off-topic for Stack Overflow, so I won't go in detail about what, when and how you might fix problems beyond referring you to the Microsoft forum (which may or may not be current at this time).

Comment: ah, i don't know the rule of "Stack Overflow" . i ask for this because i find some similar thread in Stack Overflow. I will check the thread on Microsoft social forum. thanks. and when i installed the game , it will not appear in list, and then i can't uninstall it. does wh8 has any third-party apps maneger to delete this ghost apps?

Comment: I'v read that thread , M$ has no solution for this bug. thanks a lot.

Comment: Try the Windows Phone Power tools (http://wptools.codeplex.com/) for performing install/uninstalls on your phone from your PC.